# Pseudo-inverse not producing correct output

Tags: python, matrix-inverse

I have a number of 2x2 matrices that I want to invert. When using pinv (either numpy pinv, scipy pinv, or scipy pinv2), for some of them I get an answer with elements of the order -30, which is much smaller than they should be. The matrix has a large (so non-zero) determinant, so it is invertible. If I use scipy.linalg.inv, it works fine. The matrices are all fairly similar, and the majority of them work fine with pinv.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Edit: Sorry, forgot to include an example. If I take

```
A = [[1e2, -1.6e9], [-1.6e9, 3e16]]
```

then using `np.linalg.inv` gives `[6.81e-2, 3.63e-9; 3.63e-9, 2.27e-16]`, while `np.linalg.pinv` gives `[9.48e-32, -1.77e-24; -1.77e-24, 3.33e-17]`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[1e2, -1.6e9], [-1.6e9, 3e16]])
print(np.linalg.pinv(A))
print(np.linalg.inv(A))
```

Comment: Could you give an example matrix where it fails?

Comment: @Bob Yes - sorry. I've added an example now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the matrix has very different singular values

```py
np.linalg.svd(A)[1]
```

```
[3.00000000e+16, 1.46666666e+01]
```

And [pinv](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) has a rcond=1e-15 by default, that decides decides if a singular value must or must not be included. You could simply increase the rcond

```py
np.linalg.pinv(A, rcond=1e-20) @ A
```

```
matrix([[ 9.99999996e-01,  2.06089933e-01],
        [-1.93556853e-16,  1.00000001e+00]])
```

That solves your immediate problem, but you may have to check how these ill-conditioned matrices will impact the final result.

Comment: A slight correction... The condition number is decreased, not increased to get the desired solution.

Comment: Thanks @Bob. My context for this is doing regression. So it seems the difference in magnitude is just due to the row of 1's I have included in the matrix (I only have one feature). Can I scale the feature values (e.g. divide by max value), or is that going to change things elsewhere?